# Find all followers for a user using Linq to Twitter?

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

How can I find all the followers a Twitter user has using Linq2Twitter?

All I can find in the documentation is a reference to the .Following property, not the .Followers property.

```
var result = from search in context.List
             where search.Following //etc
```

How can I find the followers a Twitter user has if I provide the twitter username?

```
twitter.com/foobar // 'foobar' is the username.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the lib is called 'to' or '2'. The logo says one thing, the text another. :P

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to Twitter lets you query the social graph for friends and followers.  Here's an example of how to get followers:

```
        var followers =
            (from follower in twitterCtx.SocialGraph
             where follower.Type == SocialGraphType.Followers &&
                   follower.ID == "15411837"
             select follower)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        followers.IDs.ForEach(id => Console.WriteLine("Follower ID: " + id));
```

That will return IDs.  Here's the full documentation: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Listing%20Followers&referringTitle=Listing%20Social%20Graphs.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API is GET [followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids) so I have to guess that the Linq2Twitter code is probably something like the [following](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20User%20Info&referringTitle=Getting%20User%20Information):

```
var users = from tweet in twitterCtx.User
                where tweet.Type == UserType.Show &&
                      tweet.ScreenName == "Sergio"
                select tweet;   
var user = users.SingleOrDefault();

var followers = user.Followers;
```

Comment: How do the thousands of Twitter applications display a list of Followers?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the `User` object doesn't have a `Followers` property.

Comment: It's entirely possible that linq2(to)twitter is an incomplete API and you'll either have to implement it yourself!

Comment: You can do so with a nice extension method! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Hopefully that's not the case, but where did you come up with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates how to get all followers of a particular user

```
var followers =
            await
            (from follower in twitterCtx.Friendship
             where follower.Type == FriendshipType.FollowerIDs &&
                   follower.UserID == "15411837"
             select follower)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (followers != null && 
            followers.IDInfo != null && 
            followers.IDInfo.IDs != null)
        {
            followers.IDInfo.IDs.ForEach(id =>
                Console.WriteLine("Follower ID: " + id)); 
        }
```

Source: [Linq2Twitter Github](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Listing-Followers)

> Note: This method call is limited to 5000 followers only. If you just need the count of followers, it might be better to scrape it off the twitter website